# How do we identify and remove escape characters from the string capture through Jenkins file

Tags: json, unix, jenkins-pipeline, devops, cicd

I have a Jenkins file, basically it runs terraform plan on a Jenkins node and captures the summary to a variable. And I am trying to send that summary back to the PR as a comment. However, for some reason it's sending escape characters which I cannot identify. And its failing to parse the json.

```
stage("plan") {
        when {
            expression { runStages }
        }
        steps {
            dir(terraformDir) {
                script {                    
                def curlOutput = sh(script: """
                     curl -L -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                     -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>“ \
                      https://github.com/api/v3/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/\${CHANGE_ID}/comments | grep -A 1 'pull_request_review_id": 147034' | grep -i "id" | awk 'NR==2 {gsub(/"id": /, ""); print}' | tr -d ','
                  """, returnStdout: true).trim()
                echo "Curl Output:\n${curlOutput}"                                        
                sh '/bin/terraform init'
                sh '/bin/terraform plan | tee plan.txt'
                def planContent = sh(script: "cat plan.txt", returnStdout: true).trim()
                echo "Plan Content: ${planContent}"
                def result = sh(script: "echo '${planContent}' | grep -oE '(Plan:.*|No changes.*)'", returnStdout: true)
                def resultOutput = result.trim()                    
                echo "Plan Output: ${resultOutput}"
                def terraform_summary = sh(script: "echo '${resultOutput}' | sed 's/\\[0m\\[1m//g'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                echo "terraform_summary: ${terraform_summary}"
                echo "CHANGE_ID: ${CHANGE_ID}"                    
                sh """
                     curl -L -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                     -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>” \
                      https://github.com/api/v3/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/\${CHANGE_ID}/comments/${curlOutput}/replies \
                      -d '{"body":"${terraform_summary}"}'
                  """
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+ curl -L -X POST -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN’> https://github.com/api/v3/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/20/comments/85703/replies -d '{"body":"No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration."}'



  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current



                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed



  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   251  100   170  100    81    911    434 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   913



{



  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",



  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-reply-for-a-review-comment"



}
```

However, if I pass the text "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration." directly the Curl call works as expected. Hence I am assuming its some escape sequences that causing the issue.

Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: You are introducing garbage yourself by:
`def terraform_summary = sh(script: "echo '${resultOutput}' | sed 's/\\[0m\\[1m//g'", returnStdout: true).trim()`. You also didn't show the content of resultOutput variable.